# Java Sql 'select sum' giving incorrect value

Tags: java, sql, select, sum

I'm not experienced in java and I'm stuck with this problem and couldn't figure out the cause for weeks. I have a sql query that selects, counts and groups by the column "name". Next in the `'while(rs.next())'` I am trying to select the sum of two other columns, a column named "kolicina" and a column named "cena" here is the code of that method:

```
public ArrayList<Artikli> getSum(String date){  
        ArrayList<Artikli> list = new ArrayList<Artikli>();
        String query = "select name, count(name) as count from izvestaj where dateZat = '"+date+"' group by name";  
        try {
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()){
                Artikli art = new Artikli();
                art.name = rs.getString("name");
                String q = "select sum(kolicina) as total from izvestaj where name = '"+art.name+"' and dateZat = '"+date+"'";
                rs2 = st2.executeQuery(q);
                while(rs2.next()){
                    art.kolicina = rs2.getInt("total");
                }
                String q1 = "select sum(cena) as total1 from izvestaj where name = '"+art.name+"' and dateZat = '"+date+"'";
                rs3 = st3.executeQuery(q1);
                while(rs3.next()){
                    art.cena = rs3.getInt("total1")/rs.getInt("count");
                }
                list.add(art);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return list;
    }
```

The problem is that the second query returns the correct sum of the column kolicina, but the third query returns result set with the sum multiplied by the count number (from the first query... That's why i divide it with the count in the end), but still, it doesn't actually return the correct ammount. Column "cena" is actually price in english, so it seems that it's making some average price and than multiplies it with the number of records... I double-checked the insert queries and they are fine, so I am sure i insert the correct values. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should check what is in the database. Or delete the sum from the last sql and look what the result is. Maybe your insert-queries are running count-times. It is difficult to say from here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of issuing two distinct queries per name, just issue

```
select name,
       sum(kolicina) as total,
       sum(cena) as total1
  from izvestaj
 where name is not null and
       dateZat = ?
 group by name
```

(re. the questino mark : read up on PreparedStatements and how to set up parameterized queries in order to protect yourself properly against SQL injections.)

(I think you can even skip the first query as its results will also be contained in this query's results.)

Comment: I changed the query as per your suggestions, it's neat and less code, but it still gives me the wrong result set. I am looking at my insert methods - can't find a mistake there either. There is a new symptom now: when i insert receipts without a discount - it gives me the correct amount, when i insert with the same percentage of discount it also gives me the correct amount, but when I combine the two (I mean when the database has records with different percentage of discount), it makes somewhat average price and the result is wrong

Comment: As Ralf Renz said, you need to look at what is actually in the database.  Not, "your insert statements", ***the database***.  You can claim "the result is wrong" all you want, if you don't show us input as well as expected results as well as actual results, you're not likely to get any other answers than the ones suggesting it's your expectations that are wrong.  SQL engines are very unlikely to produce "wrong" results for a basic query such as this.